# how make the animation runs in a infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the current code running

[MyTry](http://jsfiddle.net/Qchmqs/SxTgy/)

what i want to do is to make the animation go in a infinite loop how to do ??

i want to call the same function again or i don't know what

just that the animation go again and again when finished the last element

```
(function($) {
$.fn.fade = function() {
        return this.each(function(index, item) {
            var $this = $(this).siblings();
            $(item).hide().stop();
            if ($(item).index() == $(this).siblings().length - 1) {
                $(item).delay(5000 * index).fadeIn('slow').delay(3500).fadeOut('slow', function() { 
                    /* here is the last element finishing  */
                });

            } else {
                $(item).delay(5000 * index).fadeIn('slow').delay(3500).fadeOut('slow');

            }
        });
    };
    
})(jQuery);
 $('.tst').fade();
```

EDIT : i left the animation running and came to check for answers
so i saw a strange behavior

how to fix that as well

Comment: English uses capital letters at the start of sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YmTEV/1/) (though you'll have to adept it to your plugin-structure):

```
var elements = $('ul > li');
(function fade(idx) {
  $(elements).eq(idx || 0).fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(1500, function () {
    fade(idx < elements.length - 1 ? idx + 1 : 0);
  });
}());
```

Comment: Are there any stack issues with this solution? I didn't think JavaScript was that smart about optimizing function calls like this, but it'd be great if it is...

Comment: @Weston C: `fade` doesn't directly call itself here so the stack isn't growing. When `fade()` is executed, it can exit after executing the jQuery functions because it doesn't call the callback yet.

Answer (score 5):

The most straight-forward way is giving the function a name and call it again: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/SxTgy/4/.

```
$.fn.fade = function x() {
        var _this = this; // keep the 'this' value
```

After the final animation, call `x` again, passing the `this` value it had:

```
x.call(_this); // same as x() but it sets the 'this' value inside it correctly
```

Note that such "named function expressions" have certain quirks on IE8-.

Comment: quirks on every browser try to reduce the timing by 1/10 and see how it will do

Comment: @Qchmqs: You're setting the fading all at once. It might be a better idea to animate #1, then when it's finished start animating #2 etc. (kind of recursively). Then you're sure the second starts after the first.

Comment: yes the fading all at once are to avoid the quircks 
try to do them one after the other and you will see how they will get messed up after 2 or 3 loops

Comment: i used 7 li elements to see that clearly the first runs on all of them the secound loop make only 6 and by on you will end up with only two elemenet fadeIN and Out simultaneously